# ¿Cómo sustituir el símbolo $ de JQuery en Wordpress para evitar problemas?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

La consola de Firefox me dice:

> ReferenceError: jquery is not defined.

y es por el símbolo `$`. En otras publicaciones he visto que, usando la palabra `jQuery` se soluciona. Pero en mi script uso `$` en otras lineas.

```
var $=jQuery.noConflict();
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
var correo = document.getElementById("correo");
var mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");


jQuery(document).on('click', '#enviar', function($) 
{
    // If the value is less than 7, add a red border
    if($("#nombre").val().length < 1)
    {
        $(nombre).css("border", "3px solid red");
        $(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else
    {
        $(nombre).css("border", "1px solid ");
        $(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }

    if($("#correo").val().length < 1)
    {
        $(correo).css("border", "3px solid red");
        $(".msgerror2").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else
    {
        $(correo).css("border", "1px solid ");
        $(".msgerror2").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }

    if($("#mensaje").val().length < 1)
    {
        $(mensaje).css("border", "3px solid red");
        $(".msgerror3").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else
    {
        $(mensaje).css("border", "1px solid ");
        $(".msgerror3").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }

});
```

Por ejemplo en esta linea:      `if($("#nombre").val().length < 1)` ¿Cómo sustituyo `$` para evitar el error?

Comment: Hola @Rafael. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando en qué parte del HTML estás agregando la referencia a jQuery?

Comment: yo optaria por `if(jQuery("#nombre").val().length < 1)`

Comment: ya me funciona.. el error era que escribia jquery en vez de jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

Según nuestros compañeros de stackoverflow en ingles mencionan la siguiente solución:

Utilizar

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

y

```
JQuery.ready(function($) {
   // use $ for jQuery
}

//use $ for the other library
```

> When writing plugins to avoid problems with the usage of noConflict you can pass 'jQuery' to a function:

```
function($) {

//use $ writing your plugin

}(jQuery)
```

Referencia [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery)